# How does propagation speed on a link depend on the traffic on that link?

Tags: networking, delay

I am curious about how the propagation delay (D) on a link depends on its traffic. We know that given link length (d) and propagation speed (s), we have D:=d/s. d is obviously independent of the traffic, but what about s? For example, lets have a link, and consider two scenarios:

(A) there are already m packets on the link
(B) there are already m+n packets on the link

Assume that all other contributing parameters are constant here, and we are supposed to push another packet to the link. How does the propagation speed differ in these two cases? (Any pointer to references in the literature is also appreciated.)

Comment: "*what about s?*" -- The link speed is fixed, so it's also "*obviously independent of the traffic*".

Comment: How are you defining a link? Network wires don't store packets. Wires only contain one bit (or one modulation symbol's worth of bits) at a time. If you consider a link to have multiple packets, then you must be counting the packet buffers in the devices at one or both ends of the link as part of the link. So your question becomes "how do packet queueing/scheduling algorithms affect latency", but that doesn't quite sound like what you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model you're using for a link is about modeling how quickly information, such as individual bits (or individual modulation symbols representing a few bits' worth of data) can get down a wire or other medium. It's below the concept of packets, much less multi-packet traffic. Your model applies to even analog communication like analog telephone lines; the propagation delay of how soon the waves representing sound waves get from one analog telephone to another.

For most links, the propagation speed (s) will be roughly the speed of light. If you had a hypothetical link of some hypothetical communication technology that was so long it needed dumb relays/amplifiers along the link between the actual communicating devices, then the "rise time" of each amplifier would add to (s), which is why we can't just assume (s) is the speed of light and be done with it.